# Remove entire row only if every column within it is either $VAR1 or $VAR2

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file where column and row number will always vary, and want to remove entire rows from the txt file only if every column within it is equal to either $VAR1 or $VAR2. 
For example:

Lets say $VAR1="X" and $VAR2="N"  and I want to remove any row where $VAR1 and $VAR2 makes up the entire column.

This would be my input:

```
hajn 32 ahnnd namm 5 543 asfn F
X X N X X X N X
5739 dw 32eff Sfff 3 asd 3123 1
```

And this would be my desired output:

```
hajn 32 ahnnd namm 5 543 asfn F
5739 dw 32eff Sfff 3 asd 3123 1
```

I can solve this with a loop, but I was wondering if there's a powerful one liner way of doing this, preferably awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ VAR1=N
$ VAR2=X
$ awk -v a="$VAR1" -v b="$VAR2" '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i != a && $i != b) { print; next } }' file
hajn 32 ahnnd namm 5 543 asfn F
5739 dw 32eff Sfff 3 asd 3123 1
```

Here, we transfer the values `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` into our short `awk` script and its `a` and `b` variables using `-v` on the command line.

Inside the `awk` script, we iterate over the fields of each line, and if any field is different from both the `a` and the `b` value, we print the full line and continue with the next line immediately.

If no field is different from both `a` and `b`, nothing happens (the line is not printed).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! and nicely explained, very helpful. Thanks. I need to learn awk properly!

Answer (score 0):

You could grep out the desired results with the right choice of regex. Note: assuming the shell variables have bland chars, meaning those that are not interprettable as regex special. In case this doesn't hold true, then you can enrobe the vars in `\Q...\E` context.

```
$ grep -P "(^|\s)(?!$VAR1(\s|\$))(?!$VAR2(\s|\$))" inp
```